# How can we implement MathJax in AMP website?

Tags: mathjax

Can we able to use MathJax in AMP website. Since we have lots of maths content which required us MathJax.js. If yes how can we implement it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

include this in head

```
 <script async custom-element="amp-mathml" src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0/amp-mathml-0.1.js"></script>
```

include this in body

```
  <amp-mathml layout="container" data-formula="`<%= yourMathjax %>`">
      </amp-mathml>
```

This is how we are using Mathjax at https://amp.doubtnut.com . We are using ejs as templating engine